# Variance of X+Y upper bound

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have that $Var(X)=0.5$ and $Var(Y)=0.02$ and I am being asked for the maximum value $Var(X+5Y)$. I cannot assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables.

It can be shown that $Var(X+5Y) = 1 + 10Cov(X,Y)$. Given that the covariance can range from $(-\infty,\infty)$ then the 'maximum' value is surely infinite then, right? I am not sure how there is meant to be a finite upper bound here, when the problem gives no other information about $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The correlation between X and Y can't exceed 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the covariance is bounded by the variances of $X$ and $Y$:
$$
| \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) | \leq \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)}
$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X + 5Y) 
 & = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(5Y) + 2 \operatorname{Cov}(X,5Y) \\
 & \leq \operatorname{Var}(X) + 5^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y) + 2 \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \ 5^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y)}
\end{align}$$

Replacing the values gives:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X + 5Y) 
 & \leq 0.5 + 5^2 \times 0.02 + 2 \sqrt{0.5 \times 5^2 \times 0.02} \\
 & \leq 0.5 + 0.5 + 2 \times 0.5 \\
 & \leq 2
\end{align}$$

This is the upper bound without any assumption on the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.